# How to set default index page in Grizzly

Tags: java, grizzly

Currently in my application if I go to `http://localhost:8181/index.htm` it works great, if I go to `http://localhost:8181` I get a 404 error.  How can I tell Grizzly to load the index.htm page by default?

```
    final HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer(".", 8181);

    WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("Socket", "/");

    //enable annotation configuration
    ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextClass", "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
    ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "com.production");

    //allow spring to do all of it's stuff
    ctx.addListener("org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener");

    //enable web socket support
    final WebSocketAddOn addon = new WebSocketAddOn();
    for (NetworkListener listener : server.getListeners()) {
        listener.registerAddOn(addon);

        //if false, local files (html, etc.) can be modified without restarting the server
        listener.getFileCache().setEnabled(false);
    }

    //add jersey servlet support
    ServletRegistration jerseyServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("JerseyServlet", new ServletContainer());
    jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.production.resource");
    jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    jerseyServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    jerseyServletRegistration.addMapping("/api/*");

    //add atmosphere servlet support
    AtmosphereServlet atmosphereServlet = new AtmosphereServlet();
    AtmosphereFramework f = atmosphereServlet.framework();

    ReflectorServletProcessor r = new ReflectorServletProcessor();
    r.setServletClassName("com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet");

    f.addAtmosphereHandler("/socket/*", r);

    ServletRegistration atmosphereServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("AtmosphereServlet", atmosphereServlet);
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setInitParameter("org.atmosphere.websocket.messageContentType", "application/json");
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.production.resource");
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    //atmosphereServletRegistration.addMapping("/socket/*");
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    //serve static assets
    StaticHttpHandler staticHttpHandler = new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/web");
    server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(staticHttpHandler, "/");

    //deploy
    logger.info("Deploying server...");
    ctx.deploy(server);
```

Comment: There's currently no concept of welcome pages at the moment (at least none that I recall).  I'd suggest logging a feature request.

Comment: what happens if you rename index.htm to index.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what version of grizzly you are using, but as of 2.2.19:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-http-server/2.2.19/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/StaticHttpHandler.java

it looks like if you change your `index.htm` to `index.html` the default page should work work.

If it doesn't or you can't change your file name for some reason you could simply extend the StaticHttpHandler and override the `handle` method to make it do what you want.

Comment: The index.html works for me only on non-root level. If I map StaticHttpHandler to root / then somehow requests to localhost:8889 aren't even being processed by StaticHttpHandler. Do you know why? (I'm using grizzly 2.2.16 and jersey).

Comment: offhand, i dont know why.  i did try to change my implementation to work from root and it will not, so i am experiencing the same thing as you are.

Comment: Posted as a [bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1517?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel). But have to switch to jetty for now.

Comment: Did you get any answer for this situation? I am facing the same issue.